# Custom Google Sign In Button Doesn't Work

Tags: xcode, swiftui, google-signin

I use XCode 12 and SwiftUI for my app. Although I have directed my custom Google sign-in button to my Homescreen, it doesn't direct me when I first sign-in with google. However, after I close the app and reopen it, I seethe Homescreen right in front of me. But, how can I direct the Google sign-in button to Homescreen after signing in to Homescreen without a need to close the app and reopen it again?

Thanks for the help already!

My code for directing Google sign-in and Login buttons is below:

```
    struct Main: View{
@State var user = Auth.auth().currentUser
@State var status = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "status") as? Bool ?? false
@State var show = false
var body: some View{
    NavigationView{
    VStack{
        if user != nil{
            Home()
        }
        else if self.status{
            Home()
        }
        else{
            ZStack{
                NavigationLink(
                    destination: SignUp(show: self.$show),
                    isActive: self.$show) {
                        Text("")
                    }
                .hidden()
                Login(show: self.$show)
            }
        }
}
```

Also my code for Google sign-in button:

```
     Button(action: {
                            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.presentingViewController = UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController
                            GIDSignIn.sharedInstance()?.signIn()
                        }) {
                            HStack(spacing: 30){
                                Image ("Google Logo").resizable().renderingMode(.template).foregroundColor(.white).frame(width: 25.0, height: 25.0)
                            
                                 Text("Sign In").foregroundColor(.white).fontWeight(.bold)
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical).frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width - 200).background(Color.orange).clipShape(Capsule())
```

Comment: The short answer, your status variable doesn't automatically update when you set the UserDefaults. You should use @AppStorage in SwiftUI views instead of UserDefaults. Change this variable to '@AppStorage("status") var status: Bool?' and make sure you are setting the UserDefault at the end of GoogleSignIn.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however that variable is for the login button and it works perfectly I used user variable for the google sign-in. Maybe I'm wrong if so, please tell me because I'm very new to coding :)

Comment: The way your code is set up... "else if self.status { Home }"... ensures that if status == true, then Home() will present. If the variable status is automatically updated after signing in, then Home() will present.

Comment: The long answer, which I wasn't going to get in to, is that you should do some research on SwiftUI property wrappers (https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftui/all-swiftui-property-wrappers-explained-and-compared) before moving forward. Additionally, your logic "user != nil" and "else if self.status" are essentially checking the same thing. You should probably stick with 1 method of checking if someone is signed in to your app or things will get messy.

Comment: Thanks for the help! I will try what you've said.